# Show that the Frobenius map is onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The Frobenius map is defined as follows:

> ${\Phi}: GF(p^n) \rightarrow GF(p^n)$
>
> where ${\Phi}(x)= x^p$

I already showed that the map is a homomorphism and is 1-1.
I am left to show that it is onto.

Here is what I have so far:

Let $y \in GF(p^n) $ such that there does not exist any $x \in GF(p^n) $ that satisfies $y=x^p$

I'm not sure how to go on from here. What I know is $GF(p^n)$ contains all roots of $x^{p^n} -x$ but I don't know how to use it for the proof.

Comment: It is an injective map from a finite set to itself, so...

Comment: What is $\Phi$ applied on $$x^{p^{n-1}}\ ?$$